# Laravel URL changes when accessing from public IP

Tags: laravel, vhosts

Laravel URL change when accessing from public IP

If I join from my network to:

```
myapp.mylocalhost.com
```

(that's a virtual host on a Centos machine) that is hosted on a local machine (192.168.1.131) of my network I can see my Laravel page well.

But, If I join from outside, the URL changes to

```
myapp.mylocalhost.com/app_folder/
```

and the assets gets the IP `192.168.1.131/app_folder/public/` instead of `myapp.mylocalhost.com` as usual.

I have several page in that .131 machine, I can access to all of them from outside without a problem excep this one made with Laravel, I have almost the same vhost config for each page, what is going on?

It has to do with the .htaccess of Laravel?

The vhost file for this app is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.mylocalhost.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app_folder/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/app_folder/public>
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/ "/var/www/fcgi-bin/"
        <Directory "/var/www/fcgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_myapp.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_myapp.log combined

</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Did you change the .htaccess file from laravel in any kind?

Comment: What did you set in your config file for APP_URL Variable  (.env or /config/app.php)

Comment: @Webdesigner no, it's the default one. In both are `APP_URL=myapp.mylocalhost.com` (and in app.php: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://`myapp.mylocalhost.com'),` as I said, it works ok inside my network, but not outside...